# Why does Q-Chainage sometimes offer meters and sometimes degrees?

Tags: vector, latitude-longitude, qchainage

Q chainage is a plugin which puts regular points on a line vector at regular intervals which you can specify.

For a shapefile I've been given (and converted to line vector), it offers me to specify interval in meters.

For a shapefile I've created (and converted to line vector), it offers me degrees.

Degrees are no use to me. I want to use MY created line vector, and be offered meters by the plugin.

Answer (score 3):

Save your data in a CRS that has meters as its unit of distance. When you do, QChainage will also work in meters (it works in the units of the layer)